# Broken screen and touch on Acer CloudMobile S500, how to control?

Tags: broken-screen, remote-control

My Acer CloudMobile S500 has a broken screen and the touch don't work anymore. After that happened, I connect it to my computer with USB, and happily USB debugging was turned on so I could get all my stuff from my phone.

But my question is, how can I control my phone from my computer? My phone wasn't rooted so I really don't know how to do that without the touchscreen.

I know there are a lot of the same questions like this, but all the answers didn't help me.

Comment: If previous answers didn't help you, you need to say why: what did you try, and what happened? That's the only way you'll get answers that are more helpful to you.

Comment: Related: [Control Android with broken screen from PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42105/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Use a USB-OTG cable, then you can connect a mouse to the phone and you'll get a cursor on-screen. You can also connect the OTG cable to a USB hub, then you can connect both a mouse and keyboard. You could also connect a wired mouse long enough to pair a Bluetooth mouse/keyboard to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible scenarios I can think of:

1. Send inputs through ADB
2. If only part of the screen's touch digitizer is damaged, you can use the native Assistant Menu accessibility funtion to get a mouse pointer on-screen, trackpad style.
3. Use an adapter and plug a mouse into it, assuming they are compatible.
4. If your screen has multiple digitizers, e.g., Samsungs Note series, when one is damaged it doesn't necessarily mean the other is too; in my case, I had a phone where half the screen no longer reads finger touches, but the stylus still worked full-screen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OTG on that device, and you would need ADB authorized. the only thing left is replacing the digitizer.

Actually quite easy on that model.

Pending you have ADB:
the command is

> adb shell input tap x y

or

> adb shell input text

Practice on a working phone, I think its pixel based - vertical orientation.

so look up your pixels, measure it out - mark up some packing tape or something (make a rough grid) and then type tapes to interact