# Access to smartphone with PC

Tags: remote-access, airdroid

I've reset my phone (Android 4.3) but because the touchscreen is not fully responding, I can't go through the initial tutorial and therefore using some apps  like airdroid to remotely control my phone via PC. How can I control my phone using no apps?
Kind regards

Comment: Buy an otg cable and plug in a USB mouse

Comment: @faf Vysor could be of help: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/137530/27870

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled? You can use [key events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events) to do the initial setup in AirDroid.

Comment: @Firelord yes, USB debugging is enabled. I used OTG cabel which solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

Buy yourself a USB OTG cable. You will be able to access the phone using a mouse.

Sources:

- [1990clb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137774/access-to-smartphone-with-pc#comment175367_137774) suggestion
- personal experience
  Update:
  You should make sure your device actually supports USB OTG first.

Comment: How do you know OP's device supports USB OTG?

Comment: That is actually a good point. I assumed an Android 4.3 device would have that capability but I was wrong.