# How do I access my Android if the screen and digitizer are broken?

Tags: root-access, touchscreen, broken-screen

I have a Motorola. The OEM unlock is on and so is USB debugging. How would I access this device if I am unable to use the touch screen or see what's going on?  I am new to developing and have no idea where to start?  The phone belongs to me and  I just need to access the apps and photos, downloads, etc.  Anyone have any tips? I would greatly appreciate and thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "OEM unlock is on and so is USB debugging"? Is USB debugging via ADB possible? Have you connected the phone via USB and checked if e.g. `adb shell` works? Does "OEM unlock is on" means bootloader unlocking is possible or not?

Comment: If ADB works: [Control Android with broken screen from PC](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/control-android-with-broken-screen-from-pc)