# How to unlock Android phone without the touch screen

Tags: remote-control, huawei, physical-damage

I have a Huawei phone with Android installed. The LCD display cracked recently, and as the cracks have spread over whole display over few days, it's now totally uncontrollable.

The phone has a 4 way sort-of-joystick thingy, so when it's unlocked I can still use it. However, once the display turns off completely I cannot unlock it to use it.

Is there some key combination or a trick to unlock the phone without using the display? The phone is not password or key locked, it just requires to slide from left to right.

I have USB debugging enabled, but I have no idea how to use it. The phone is not rooted.

Also, I'm wondering how I'm going to save my phonebook and other stuff.

The device name is Huawei U8500.

Comment: You might wish to check our other [broken screen questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=broken+screen), which already have helpful answers; e.g. [My screen got broken, how to see on the computer what I'm doing in my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36860/16575) / [Control Android with broken screen from PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42105/16575) / [Broken Screen + Using adb shell to run vnc server](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19317/16575) / [What can I do with an Nexus One with a broken LCD?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/10341/16575)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [USB cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BQVK2PU) and buy a USB mouse so that you can use that [a mouse] instead of touch screen. Check out a USB adapter for Android that fits your budget [and make sure it's compatible with your device] and purchase it.

Comment: I have a simple female-female adapter. Won't using this short-circuit the device or something?

Comment: No, I don't see why it should. I do the same with my Galaxy S3. You shouldn't have a problem, unless the cable itself already has its problems, but if the wire works well you should be fine.

Comment: I'll try it then. If the phone breaks... well, I don't know who you are, but I'll find you and I'll eat you.

Comment: Lol. I didn't know cannibalism was legal. But I don't see why it should be bad. Test it out for five to ten minutes. If you sense something, don't. And unless you have a weak device, it should work perfectly. Assuming all devices, ports and cables aren't ruined and are in great condition.

Comment: Do you really think I'd reward bad advice by something *legal*? However, so far, the mouse does not work. Maybe it doesn't have that two-way port at all.
I'll try some more mouses, but well, it's Huawei - I don't expect much.

Comment: I really hoped to hack into the phone using debug mode - but that really seems to be impossible. Androind ain't that open as they state, or my firmware was heavily modified.
I guess once somebody develops firmware that provides easy restore of data from smartphones with broken display, he's gonna drown in money. Many of my problems had the same problem.

Comment: Well, maybe. Bad advice is good for others, as they say what works for me may not work for you. But I really hope it works. Have you considered a wireless Bluetooth mouse? Hmm... Android seems very open to me, I've been able to do endless things with mine. But I think that comes with the fact because I develop apps so know ways around. I'll look into your device and find ways to open up your device more so the USB works.

Comment: But your device name helps. Let me know if you find other mice that work. If not, maybe a better adapter would work or a device modification. Perhaps Bluetooth is the best bet for your device specifically. Don't know the hardware there. NY has quite different than others.

Comment: I'm so stupid... Well, I've updated device name in the question, I've totally forgotten about that. Bluetooth mouse might not help since bluetooth can't be turned on...

Comment: You're not stupid, but thanks. I'll look into it now. And why can't Bluetooth be turned on? Strange.

Comment: Because I cannot unlock the device, because it cannot be controlled using the display, because the display is broken. There is no HW switch on it - and again, I can't figure how to contol it via USB conection, even though I hope it's possible.

Comment: What Android version do you have, again? Also, according to searches so far a USB mouse should be of use, assuming your Android OS is updated. In addition, [not sure if you'll find this of use] Puffin Browser includes a mouse simulator, so you can use a touchpad within the browser, as well as a game controller if you game. Other than that, I think you should be fine if your Android is updated.

Answer (score 3):

> **Requirements**

- Your phone must be **rooted**
- You need a **USB** Cable
- You need a **PC**
- **USB Debugging** must be enabled
- **Android SDK** or at least **ADB** must be installed on the PC
- You need to be familiar with **Command prompts/Terminals**

> **Tutorial**

1. **Connect** your phone to the **PC**
2. Open up a **Command Prompt**
3. To connect the Phone Terminal, Run **`adb shell`**
4. To emulate a Power Button (To power on the device), Run **`input keyevent 26`**
5. To Unlock the screen, Run **`input keyevent 82`**
6. Your phone now is Unlocked!

> **Notes**

- This didn't work for me but it's confirmed to work with others

> **References**

- To see a list of useful **ADB** Commands, Visit [this](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/01/handy-adb-commands-for-android.html) Site

> **Advices**

- Install a VNC Server on the Phone such as [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dorg.onaips.vnc%26hl%3Den&ei=WvrXU4nROuLG7Abwn4CYCg&usg=AFQjCNFen5XM9iTdz-HVAqF28IoGNJ5R9Q&sig2=0n_ihv2hFI5k-O_VFqMRkg&bvm=bv.71778758,d.ZGU) one, and install a Client on a PC such as [This](http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/) one, and connect the PC to the phone and then you can use the phone on the PC directly

Comment: That's hardly a useful answer for me, don't you think?

Comment: @TomášZato That's not an easy thing to get around it easily, don't you think?

Comment: Oh, well actually I expected the Android developers to think when they are making the systems. To think means to ask questions (and find the answers). One of the first questions should be: "*What can our user do when the screen is broken?*" I don't implicitly expect people to be dumb, therefore I thought they asked themselves the question. Because they obviously *didn't*, I guess my expectation about them was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an USB OTG (on the go) adapter and a USB hub, plug the OTG in your phone put the hub in the adapter and plug in an  USB keyboard and USB mouse

Answer (score 0):

Try [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fosshub.com/MyPhoneExplorer.html). Works like a charm for me. I have Android Gingerbread 2.3.5.

Comment: You've joined the site today and have left two answers, both suggesting the same product. What's your affiliation to this app? Please have a look at our [help/behavior], specifically the section on promotion.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a mouse using a USB Female Cable. I can use this cable to control my Huawei Assend. Then you can remove the lock to avoid interruption.

Comment: He says it currently doesn't have a lock but still has the slide, does the mouse get rid of that?

Comment: yes the mouse full replace the touch