# Sync saved wifi passwords from defected mobile

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-note-2, password

I had an accident few days ago and broke the screen of my Samsung Galaxy Note 2, everything in it is working fine, even the touching system is working fine as well, but I want to retrive the saved wifi passwords, I looked over the internet, though if I could sync the screen of the mobile with my PC, though about the synced passwords on google, non of them could help.

I have purchased samsung galaxy tab 3, logged in using same account and tried to retrive the saved passwords from google account, but it seams that there is nothing saved there.

can you please advice how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible approaches:

1. If you have Google Cloud Backup activated on the "old" device, your WiFi passwords have been stored along (plain text, by the way). So starting with a new (or factory-reset) device, you should be asked on account creation whether to enable it here as well. Answering with "yes" will restore several things even from your old device, including WiFi passwords (for details, please see [Google Backup: Multiple devices using the same account - what happens on Restore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42245/16575))
2. If both devices have root access, you can use either a dedicated tool like [WiFi Pass Recovery & Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.ryanamaral.wifi.passwords), or straight go for a full-fledged solution like [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)
3. If at least the "old" device has root access, you can obtain your passwords from their configuration file directly. They are usually stored in `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` using plain-text.

Comment: THanks for the great summary,I tried to sync from Google Cloud Backup but it synced 1 old wifi password which means that the sync to the cloud was turned off (I guess), but in the end I don't have it saved on the cloud.
And for the root, non of them is rooted and for the "old" one I cannot root it with a broken screen.

Comment: but I have been wondering if I can sync the screen to PC or maybe turn it on, using google play on the computer try to install an application that works as Spy allows me to access to it using another device "using new device", same idea of teamviewer but buthg without IDs, just standing in installing the app, do you think something like that is available?

Comment: See e.g. [Broken Screen + Using adb shell to run vnc server](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19317/16575) / [Control Android with broken screen from PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42105/16575) / [What can I do with an Nexus One with a broken LCD?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/10341/16575) / [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12834/16575)